# Upgrade to windows 10 after motherboard change

Tags: windows-7

I upgraded to Win 10. Stayed on it for a while but had some problems, so I went back to Windows 7 to see if it solved my problems. It did.
I had to replace my motherboard and now I am having sound issues that I can't resolve under Win 7. I want to back to Win 10, but I don't think my hardware change is going to allow it without a key. I don't think my "stored Win 10 key" in the cloud will suffice.
Any thoughts?

Comment: That's the problem of clinging to old stuff. Often new hardware is NOT compatible.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think my "stored Win 10 key" in the cloud will suffice. Any thoughts?

Windows 1607+ allows you to link your digital entitlement to Windows 10 to your Microsoft account.

> In Windows 10 (Version 1607 or later), you can link your Microsoft account to the Windows 10 digital license on your device. This can help you reactivate Windows using the Activation troubleshooter if you make a significant hardware change later, such as replacing the motherboard.

It is worth pointing out if you didn't link your digital entitlement to your Microsoft Account then these instructions will not be possible.

> If you didn't add your Microsoft account and link it to the digital
> license on your device, you won't be able to use the Activation
> troubleshooter to reactivate Windows after a hardware change.
>
> [image]

[Reactivating Windows 10 after a hardware change](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/20530/windows-10-reactivating-after-hardware-change)

Comment: I understand an existing answer already exists that links to the same page.  However, the existing answer does not contain the relevant information from the linked paged.  *The answer also failed to provide the instructions on how to activate after a significant hardware change.*

Answer (score -1):

Your concerns are well merited. Microsoft has provided measures to allow a user to successfully reactivate Windows 10 after a hardware change(in your case the motherboard). However there is 1 caveat. Prior to the hardware change, you need to have been on Version 1607 or later for this feature to work. If not, then you  will need to purchase a valid Windows 10 key. Hope that helps.

More Info:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/20530/windows-10-reactivating-after-hardware-change